# AWS ECR Scanner finds no vulnerability in alpine image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I'm using ECR Image Scanning to scan docker image. When I select `python:3.10.9-slim` as base image I find the following result:

```
Vulnerabilities found:
  1 Critical 
  7 High 
 25 Medium 
 12 Low 
145 Informational 
 56 Undefined 
=================
246 Total
```

It seems normal(to me atleast). As some of issues came from the linux kernel, which I'm assuming because of the host server.(As described [here](https://www.brettlischalk.com/posts/ecr-image-scanning-gotchas)) 
But when I select `3.10.4-alpine3.14` as base image, the scanner gives the following output:

```
Findings
Vulnerabilities found:
  0 Critical 
  0 High 
  0 Medium 
  0 Low 
  0 Informational 
  0 Undefined 
=================
  0 Total
```

Is it normal not finding any vulnerability? At least I was expecting some vulnerability from the host server's kernel(as with `python:3.10.9-slim`). I also tried with some other version of python-alpine image, but got the same result. Is there any issue with the alpine image?
Thanks.

Comment: It's normal to have no vulnerability.  Having 246 (!!) vulnerabilities is a big STOP signal.